Big difference in fio randwrite my result and datasheet result for disk
I'm doing a fio nvme test on a Samsung gen 4 disk. The test results are similar to those in the datasheet, but randwrite differs by almost 5 times. I took the settings for the test from the datasheet  4KB (4,096 bytes) of data transfer size in Queue Depth=32 by 4 workers
The results I get



Sequential Read
6741 MB/s




Sequential Write
4027 MB/s


Random Read
1056K IOPS


Random Write
920K IOPS




rand_write: (g=0): rw=randwrite, bs=(R) 4096B-4096B, (W) 4096B-4096B, (T) 4096B-4096B, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=32
...
fio-3.34
Starting 4 processes
Jobs: 4 (f=4): [w(4)][100.0%][w=3585MiB/s][w=918k IOPS][eta 00m:00s]
rand_write: (groupid=0, jobs=4): err= 0: pid=419160: Thu Jun 27 15:10:57 2024
  write: IOPS=929k, BW=3628MiB/s (3804MB/s)(425GiB/120001msec); 0 zone resets
    slat (nsec): min=1105, max=4923.5k, avg=2131.83, stdev=1574.82
    clat (usec): min=11, max=15470, avg=135.25, stdev=40.34
     lat (usec): min=13, max=15554, avg=137.38, stdev=40.54
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[  109],  5.00th=[  117], 10.00th=[  121], 20.00th=[  125],
     | 30.00th=[  129], 40.00th=[  133], 50.00th=[  135], 60.00th=[  137],
     | 70.00th=[  139], 80.00th=[  141], 90.00th=[  143], 95.00th=[  153],
     | 99.00th=[  231], 99.50th=[  247], 99.90th=[  310], 99.95th=[  408],
     | 99.99th=[ 1221]
   bw (  MiB/s): min= 2110, max= 4220, per=100.00%, avg=3631.51, stdev=72.23, samples=956
   iops        : min=540390, max=1080339, avg=929666.36, stdev=18491.86, samples=956
  lat (usec)   : 20=0.01%, 50=0.01%, 100=0.31%, 250=99.28%, 500=0.38%
  lat (usec)   : 750=0.02%, 1000=0.01%
  lat (msec)   : 2=0.01%, 4=0.01%, 10=0.01%, 20=0.01%
  cpu          : usr=21.24%, sys=61.52%, ctx=19177737, majf=0, minf=90
  IO depths    : 1=0.1%, 2=0.1%, 4=0.1%, 8=0.1%, 16=0.1%, 32=100.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.1%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=0,111451144,0,0 short=0,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=32

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
  WRITE: bw=3628MiB/s (3804MB/s), 3628MiB/s-3628MiB/s (3804MB/s-3804MB/s), io=425GiB (457GB), run=120001-120001msec

Disk stats (read/write):
  nvme0n1: ios=92/111222969, merge=0/0, ticks=10/13512913, in_queue=13512924, util=99.87%

The results are in the datasheet
Random 4KB Read  (Up to) IOPS 1000K
Random 4KB Write (Up to) IOPS 200K

Random performance in Table 3 was measured by using FIO 2.7 in Linux Gen3: CentOS6(kernel 3.14), Gen4: CentOS7(Kernel 5.3.1) with 4KB (4,096 bytes) of data transfer size in Queue Depth=32 by 4 workers. Measurements were performed on a full Logical Block Address (LBA) span of the drive in sustained state. The actual performance
may vary depending on use conditions and environment.

Sequential 128KB Read  (Up to) 6700
Sequential 128KB Write (Up to) 4000

Sequential performance in Table 4 was measured by using FIO 2.7 in Linux Gen3: CentOS6(kernel 3.14), Gen4: CentOS7(Kernel 5.3.1) with 128KB (131,072 bytes) of data
transfer size in Queue Depth=32 by 1 worker.

The job I use.
[global]
ioengine=libaio
iodepth=32
blocksize=4K
direct=1
buffered=0
runtime=120
numjobs=4
time_based
filename=/dev/nvme0n1
stonewall
group_reporting


[rand_write]
rw=randwrite


You should pre-condition the drives before running 4k random write test. I usually run 4k randwrite load for 3-4 hours, before actual test to get actual results. You need to do workload pre-condition before write test. https://ssdcentral.net/test-ssd-performance-like-the-pros/

looks good. while the disk is empty, it is easy to write to it. I will check and write about the result.

and so, if the disk is 100% busy, then the randwrite speed is 130-150k iops.

Which is expected and correlates with numbers from Samsung.

Your fio result is random 4k writes. That spec sheet is sequential 128k writes. Very different, not comparable.
When IOPS is a limiting factor, a larger block size will be more data transferred per second.

Making this benchmark relevant to your capacity planning of real applications is another matter:

What is the read/write distribution? 100% writes seems unlikely.
Does the application use Linux libaio?
File system or no?
How many IOPS do you require for good performance? Hundreds of thousands of random IOPS is sufficient for some databases with a very large number of concurrent users.


I didn't understand your answer.
My task now is to check whether the disk corresponds to what is written in the datasheet. The disk has no file system. The disk is formatted. I created a job from the disk datasheet. In the question I described what I get and what values ​​​​for comparison in the datasheet.

The datasheet spec is 4000 MB/s sequential writes of 128k size. You tested random 8k writes, a much more difficult test.   Change blocksize  and rw.

My question was about Random Write. Аs you can see in my question, the only difference is Random Write. There is no problem in other tests.
